# Converting hyphenated string to text in excel

Tags: excel

I have a bunch of hyphenated numbers in the form "11-2011.00, 11-2011.01...". These are technical census codes, not dates, but I want to drop the decimal and the two digits following it in excel without converting to the date.

In other words, I want to go from 11-2011.00 to 11-2011

Comment: Do they all have the `.00` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Set the format of the target cells to type `text`. This should prevent the conversion to `date` type.

Answer (score 0):

If your data always has that consistent length, you could use (where A1 is your data):

> =left(A1,7)

If the length of the string will fluctuate before the ".", and you always want to take the values up to the point of the ".", then you could use

> =left(A1,find(".",A1)-1)

Note that excel will still read this as a date, but as long as the cell format is 'general' instead of 'date', this should not change how it displays.

Somewhat related - when I use technical codes like this in a master index list, I like to create helper columns showing each individual portion of the code (Company ID, cost center, GL #, etc.). To do this, you need some level of uniformity in your data. Generally you need either consistent string length or consistent 'break' characters.

The text modifiers you will likely use will be (1) 'left', which takes text starting at the first character of a string, for a given number of characters; (2) 'right', which takes text starting at the final character of a string, for a given number of characters; (3) 'mid', which takes text from a specified starting spot within a string, for a given number of characters; and (4) 'find', which looks for the first character where a specified search term appears in a string ['search' is equivilent to 'find', but is not case sensitive].

I find that creating additional index columns like this makes future referencing in other formulas more understandable to the reader - such as creating a sumifs formula which looks for a specified cost center in a specified company code.